# IE and string matching

Tags: javascript, mootools, string-matching

I'm trying to get an array of all links on a page whose href matches a specific string (part of the url). This method works in all browsers but IE, and I'm not sure why.

```
var url = '/work.php?subsection=1';
a = $('clients').getElements('a[href^='+url+']');
alert(a.length);
```

I'm using Mootools which would explain the `$('clients').getElements()` bit.

In all browsers but IE `a.length` returns 10. IE returns 0. Anyone know why??

It's worth mentioning that I only need the first part of the href to match. So `<a href="/work.php?subsection=1&project=11"></a>` should match.

Comment: This should probably be tagged with `Mootools`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing which version of Mootools you're using, and without seeing the markup of the page, it's difficult to give an answer.

Could IE be treating the URLs as though they are fully qualified? In other words, instead of starting with `/work.php?subsection=1`, could IE believe the URLs start with `http://yourdomain.com/`?

Edit: As a work around, you could use the `[att*=val]` selector, which matches based on whether attribute simply contains the specified value. If you feel that your URL might contain `/work.php?subsection=1` somewhere other than the beginning, and you *really* don't want to match those, you could throw your domain in there, too.

Comment: You know what? I think that's it, goddammit. Ack! Why the hell is it doing that? Do I have to grab the domain, too?

Comment: Please see my edit! I'm glad you ran into this problem before I did... I could imagine this ruining my day at some point.

Comment: You really saved my butt tonight. `[att*=val]` worked perfectly. Thank you!!! Been struggling with this for a few hours.

Comment: if you run into similar difficulties you an always use the array .filter like so: `node.getElements("a").filter(function(el) { return el.get("href").contains("somestring"); });`